# replace for loop with apply in R within a function

Tags: r, apply, r-raster

I have created a function which requires a raster and a matrix.Every row of the matrix holds the coordinates of a cell in the raster. After finishing my function returns a vector which contains the number of every cell that is saved in my matrix via it's coordinates:

```
library(raster)
library(gdistance)
r <- raster(nrow=100,ncol=15)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
plot(r)
pts <- matrix(c(-144,72.9,-168,45.9,-144,13.5),ncol=2,nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)

get_cells <- function(raster,points_matrix) {
Cells <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(points_matrix))
    {
    Cells[i] <- cellFromXY(raster,c(points_matrix[i,]))
    }
    return(Cells)

}
```

Now I would like to restructure my function so that I can use it with `apply()`.
So in the end I want to be able to type something like:

```
apply(pts,1,get_cells)
```

and get the same result, but I can't figure out how to do it.
Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: where did you define `points_matrix` ??

Comment: I didn't, it is a parameter of the function I create and one has to assign the `pts` -matrix to it when calling the function. So in order to run the fuction you'll have to type: `get_cells(r,pts)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define one line function within `apply` function. Try this

```
apply(pts,1,function(x) return(cellFromXY(raster,x)))
```

EDIT:
@snoops `apply` does takes user defined functions also like yours. Your Problem is you have two input arguments in your function while your code with apply you are providing only one argument. And you do not need loop inside your function.

```
get_cells <- function(x,raster) {
    Cells <- cellFromXY(raster,x)
    return(Cells)
}
```

Now this will work. You can give other arguments of your function inside apply function itself like this.

```
apply(pts,1,getCells,raster = r)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code worked well. Unfortunately the example I gave is a simplified excerpt of a much larger script so a one line function won't work for me. I didn't know `apply()` only takes one line functions...if I did I wouldn't have asked :D So I guess I will have to look for another syntax. Anyway, thanks again for helping me out !

Comment: Pls accept the answer and give upvote if it works for u :-)

Comment: I did but it said I need at least 15 reputation for my vote to be displayed...hope my vote still counts though